# Displaying Dates using specific format

Tags: r, date

I am using R and have constructed a set of dates, and want to print the dates. When using as.Date and format, the dates are printed as I wish

```
 dates_Malta <- seq(as.Date('29-02-2020', format='%d-%m-%Y'), by='days',
               length=ldays_Malta)
 as.Date(dates_Malta, "%d-%m-%Y")
 format(dates_Malta, format="%d-%m-%Y")
```

However, if I use cat, I get numbers without any formatting applied. What is happening.

```
 cat("dates_Malta", as.Date(dates_Malta, "%d-%m-%Y"), "\n")
```

Comment: Which language you are talking about?

Comment: Apologies. I am using R.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to character before using `cat()` with `as.character()`.

```r
dates_Malta <- seq(as.Date('29-02-2020', format='%d-%m-%Y'), by='days',
                   length=10)
as.Date(dates_Malta, "%d-%m-%Y")
#>  [1] "2020-02-29" "2020-03-01" "2020-03-02" "2020-03-03" "2020-03-04"
#>  [6] "2020-03-05" "2020-03-06" "2020-03-07" "2020-03-08" "2020-03-09"
format(dates_Malta, format="%d-%m-%Y")
#>  [1] "29-02-2020" "01-03-2020" "02-03-2020" "03-03-2020" "04-03-2020"
#>  [6] "05-03-2020" "06-03-2020" "07-03-2020" "08-03-2020" "09-03-2020"

cat("dates_Malta", as.Date(dates_Malta, "%d-%m-%Y"), "\n")
#> dates_Malta 18321 18322 18323 18324 18325 18326 18327 18328 18329 18330

cat("dates_Malta", as.character(as.Date(dates_Malta, "%d-%m-%Y")), "\n")
#> dates_Malta 2020-02-29 2020-03-01 2020-03-02 2020-03-03 2020-03-04 2020-03-05 2020-03-06 2020-03-07 2020-03-08 2020-03-09
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There is also a related problem that doing the following, the result
still uses - as a separator, rather than /

```
 strDt <- as.Date(dates_Italy, format='%d/%m/%Y')
 strDt
```